# Dummy variable with multiple conditions

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement, conditional-statements, dummy-variable

Suppose I have a dataframe "df" with 2 columns: x and y. They contain numerical real numbers (both positive and negative). I need to create a dummy variable named, dummy_var, which follows the following condition:

dummy_var = 1 if , -100 < x < -90, -80 < x < -50, and 50 < y < 45

dummy_var = 0, otherwise

This is what I tried:

```
df$dummy_var = 0
df$dummy_var[df$y > 50, df$y < 45 , df$x > -100,df$x < -90, df$x > -80 
& df$x < -50 ] = 1
```

I am getting error after placing the minus sign after the relational operator. Not sure how to debug it.

```
incorrect number of subscripts on matrix
Traceback:
```

Also, the code that I wrote is probably inefficient. So, if you have better suggestions to write the code, that would also be very helpful.

Comment: You may need `&` or `|` instead of `,`

Comment: Thanks. I've edited it now. It was a typo. But the problem at large was not with the "&" operator, but how to write a negative number after the relational < and > signs. R is not able to interpret the "-" sign it seems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `|` with `&` to create the logical expression

```
i1 <- with(df, (x > -100  & x <- 90)|(x > -80 & x < -50)|(y > 50 & y < 45))
df1dummy_var[i1] <- 1
```